# How to get the difference between two JodaTime LocalTime stamps?

Tags: java, jodatime, localtime

I am using [JodaTime LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) in order to specify times. How can I get the difference in minutes between two times?

```
LocalTime startT = new LocalTime(6,30);
LocalTime endT = new LocalTime(12,15);

// LocalTime duration = this.endT.minusMinutes(startT);
// int durationMinutes = duration.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you ask

> How can I get the difference in minutes between two times?

then I would think of following more intuitive solution:

```
LocalTime startT = new LocalTime(6,30);
LocalTime endT = new LocalTime(12,15);
int minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(startT, endT).getMinutes(); // 345m = 6h - 15m
```

The expression

```
Period.fieldDifference(startT, endT).getMinutes()
```

will only yield `-15` that means not taking in account the hour difference and hence not converting the hours to minutes. If the second expression is really what you want then the question should rather be like:

How can I get the difference between the minute-parts of two `LocalTime`-instances?

### Updated for Java-8:

```
LocalTime startT = LocalTime.of(6,30);
LocalTime endT = LocalTime.of(12,15);

long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startT, endT);

System.out.println(minutes); // output: 345

// Answer to a recommendation in a comment:
// Attention JSR-310 has no typesafety regarding units (a bad design choice)
// => UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Minutes
minutes = Duration.between(startT, endT).get(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: In java 8 :   `java.time.Duration.between(startLocalTime, endLocalTime).get(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);`

Comment: @MickaëlGauvin Thanks for your efforts, but please see my updated answer regarding your comment.

Comment: yes all ChronoUnits are not handled  for the method get.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question properly the following should do the job:

```
Period diff = Period.fieldDifference(startT, endT);
int minutes = diff.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Incorrect. See the [answer by Meno Hochschild](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22376524/642706) for correction,